# HighStock Library: How to keep the same color for each segment in case of selecting

Tags: animation, highcharts, pie-chart

I want to have everything like this example

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-allowpointselect-pie/

but ion the application it works slightly different. When I am clicking on the segment it changes the color after animation. So it works like this example, if I will change the rows 
from

```
   `series: {allowPointSelect: true}`
```

to

```
    series: {
       allowPointSelect: true, 
       states: {
           select : {
                color: '#00FF00'        
           }                
       }                        
    }
```

`

What is the problem, could someone help me to understand this problem

Comment: It doesn't appear that you've given enough information to go on. You are trying to reproduce the example? or is that your code? "it works slightly different ... what is the problem?" is not a very good question. Please be more specific.

Comment: Please open these links and click on the segment of the chart. In case of the second example you will see that it changes the color. In the my application the configurations from the first example (in the fiddle it doesn't change the color)  are working like second example, so it changes the color in case of clicking, but it shouldn't change. Is there any configuration which will disable this feature completely? I want to have animation, but I want to keep the same color as well, when user will click on segment.

Comment: 1. http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-allowpointselect-pie/

2. http://jsfiddle.net/MmJ4t/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have different version of Highcharts - maybe some old version has that kind of bug?

Anyway, try to set `color: null` directly. See:

```
    plotOptions: {
       series: {
           allowPointSelect: true, 
           states: {
               select : {
                   color: null       
               }                
           }                        
        }
    },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MmJ4t/2/

If this won't help, the only solution may be to set for each point directly selected color:

```
    series: [{
        data: [{ 
                y: 29.9, 
                states: { 
                    select: {
                        color: 'red'
                    }
                } 
               }, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
    }]
```

Comment: Pawel, I've tried it with same version which is used in the example above. And other options mentioned by you don't help as well, even when I am setting selected color for each series. The interesting point that it uses the color of the first series for selection.

Comment: I'm not setting selected color for series, but for each point. Could you post link to your page (some demo)? Then we may help you more.

Comment: Hi Pawel. Thank you very much for your help and time. you are right, now it works when I am setting the selected color for each point and not for each series.